# PrincipalContext has exception when using Impersonation in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, impersonation

I am building an ASP.NET Web API to retrieve Active Directory information using .NET Framework 4.8. The IIS is set to Windows authentication only.

The code works ok on my local machine, but does not work when accessing the API on a client computer.

The issue is from this code:

```
WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(((WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).AccessToken, () => {
      var principleContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, ConfigHelper.AdRoot);                    
 });
```

After getting the `principalContext`, `principalContext.ConnectedServer` throws an exception

> 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A71, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection.

If I remove the `RunImpersonated` part, the code works fine. When I visit the Web API from the server, the impersonation also works.

Please help, thank you!

I guess it might be a double hop issue, but I cannot confirm.